# Computing Integral Closures

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

I'm wondering if there's an algorithm, or a program I can use, to compute integral closures. Specifically, what I have in mind are variants of questions of the sort: what is the integral closure of ℤ[x] in Quot(ℚ[x,y]/fℚ[x,y]), for some specific f(x,y).

Comment: The first five results Google returns for "integral closure algorithm" are links to (different) papers titled "An algorithm for computing the integral closure," for example http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9704017 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for prepackaged software, [Macaulay II](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.3.1/share/doc/Macaulay2/IntegralClosure/html/index.html) can do the job.

Comment: for the link:"Gone

The requested resource
/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.3.1/share/doc/Macaulay2/IntegralClosure/html/index.html
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource."

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the papers, there's even a book! ["Integral closure: rees algebras, multiplicities, algorithms"](http://books.google.com/books?id=EjAgB_uVvxEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=wolmer+vasconcelo&ei=eGNOS_kOlZTOBPnsqfML&cd=4#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Vasconcelos.